# Fail to connect to VREP remote api in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I want to connect to VREP using the python remote api in google colab. I tried to run the sample code below in jupyter notebook and it is working. However, when I change to google colab, the remote api fails to connect to VREP even though the code is the same.

```
import vrep 

vrep.simxFinish(-1)
clientID = vrep.simxStart('127.0.0.1', 19997, True, True, 500, 5) 

if clientID != -1: # if we connected successfully
    print ('Connected to remote API server')
else:
    print('Fail to connect')
```

Comment: Have you started the server on your Colab backend? (When operating in Colab, the IP `127.0.0.1` will point to the Colab backend VM rather than your local machine.)

Comment: Sorry, but how do I know if I started the server on colab backend? So, what IP should I use to point to my local machine?